# How to get the entire document HTML as a string keeping the input values?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to keep the form input values when I do something like this `document.documentElement.outerHTML`

Comment: Could you show the what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

The value does not update the attribute. So if you want the attribute to be updated, you manually need to do it before you read the html.

```js
var myForm = document.querySelector('form')
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')

myForm.addEventListener('submit', function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault()
  inputs.forEach( function (inp) {
    inp.setAttribute('value', inp.value)
  })
 console.log(myForm.outerHTML)
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="bar" value="one" />
  <input name="foo" value="two" />
  <button>Click</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Note that the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.